# Convert Array object into Json in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

How can I convert this:

```
var expenseList = [[1,"Beverages"],
                   [2,"Condiments" ],
                    [3,"Confections" ],
                   [4,"Dairy Products" ],
                   [5,"Grains/Cereals" ],
                   [6,"Meat/Poultry" ],
                    [7,"Produce" ],
                   [8,"Seafood" ]];
```

into this:

```
output = [
               { value: 1, text: "Beverages" },
               { value: 2, text: "Condiments" },
               { value: 3, text: "Confections" },
               { value: 4, text: "Dairy Products" },
               { value: 5, text: "Grains/Cereals" },
               { value: 6, text: "Meat/Poultry" },
               { value: 7, text: "Produce" },
               { value: 8, text: "Seafood" }
        ];
```

The first data source can be taken as input and the second is the required output. 
I tried converting the array into a type of string using a loop and then parse the string into json but Json.pasre throws error there.

```
var list = '';
for (var i = 0; i < expenseList.length; i++) {
        var showText = expenseList[i][1].replace('"', '\\"');
        var key = expenseList[i][0];

    list = '{ value: ' + key + ', text: "' + value + '"},' + list;
}

    list = '[' + list.substr(0, list.length - 1) + ']';
    var bindList;
    bindList = JSON.parse(list);
```

Comment: Trying to build up a JSON object as a string is very error-prone.

Comment: There are exactly 0 (zero) "JSON objects" in your required output. Or anything else remotely JSON-related for that matter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

simply try

```
var output = expenseList.map(function(val){
  return { value: val[0], text: val[1] }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```
var list = expenseList.map(function(x) {
  return {
     value: x[0],
     text: x[1]
  };
});
```

To then turn into JSON you can use

```
var json = JSON.stringify(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative solution that builds up the array in the way you were trying, but is more correct:

```
var expenseList = [[1,"Beverages"],
                   [2,"Condiments" ],
                   [3,"Confections" ],
                   [4,"Dairy Products" ],
                   [5,"Grains/Cereals" ],
                   [6,"Meat/Poultry" ],
                   [7,"Produce" ],
                   [8,"Seafood" ]];

var list = [];
for (var i = 0; i < expenseList.length; i++) {
    var val = expenseList[i][0];    
    var txt = expenseList[i][1];

    list.push({value: val, text: txt});
}

console.log(list);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want an array and hash object meets your requirement then use this.

loadash used.

```
_.zipObject(_.map(expenseList,0),_.map(expenseList,1))
```

Output will be

```
{1: "Beverages", 2: "Condiments", 3: "Confections", 4: "Dairy Products", 5: "Grains/Cereals", 6: "Meat/Poultry", 7: "Produce", 8: "Seafood"}
```

Answer (score 0):

One liner solution using [.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```
var expenseList = [[1,"Beverages"],[2,"Condiments" ],[3,"Confections" ],[4,"Dairy Products" ],[5,"Grains/Cereals" ],[6,"Meat/Poultry" ],[7,"Produce" ],[8,"Seafood" ]],
      output = expenseList.map(([value,text])=>({value:+value,text})); 

console.log(output);
```

Comment: What is change in your answer then others